# Can I compile an XQuery into a package using Saxon - or - how to minimize compile times

Tags: xquery, saxon

I'm using the dotnet Saxon9ee-api.

I have a very large schema (180,000 lines), and a schema aware XQuery.

When I compile it, it understandably takes several seconds to compile it. That's life.

But is there a way that I can compile it once, and serialise it to disk as a compiled entity? So that I can load it again later and use it?

(The XSLT compiler allows me to compile into XsltPackages, that I'm pretty sure will let me do this with XSLT).

Comment: https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.9/schema-processing/scm.html is what you are looking for (if the .NET API exposes the import/export feature, not quite sure whether there is an equivalent for https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation9.9/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/SchemaManager.html#importComponents-javax.xml.transform.Source- on the .NET side)

Comment: I'll give that a go and see how effective it is, ideally I was hoping that somehow the XsltPackage paradigm was available, but if I can make an XQuery compile in < 1 second, then thats probably good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no filestore format for compiled XQuery code in Saxon (unlike XSLT), but there is a filestore format for compiled schemas (the SCM format) and this may help. However, loading a schema this large will not be instantaneous.

Note that the compile time for XSD schemas can be very sensitive to the actual content of the schema. In particular, large finite bounds can be very costly (example maxOccurs="1000"). This is due to the algorithms used to turn a grammar into a finite state machine. Saxon optimises the textbook algorithm for some cases, but not for all. The finite state machine is held in the SCM file, so you won't incur the cost if loading from an SCM file; however, the FSMs that are expensive to compute also tend to be very large, so if you're in this situation, the SCM is going to be big and therefore slower to read.